# How to check if remote file is image using get_headers

Tags: php

```
$headers = get_headers("http://www.domain.com/image.jpg");
```

How do I make sure the file is an actual image using this?

Answer (score 4):

Not at all. The headers might or might not tell you (via `Content-type`), what the server **thinks** this is - but nothing hinders you to put e.g. `myfile.zip` on a webserver, then rename it to `myfile.jpg`. The webserver will serve it with `Content-type: image/jpeg`, which it definitly is not.

Comment: I'm just looking to do an initial check before downloading the image. The secondary check is done with getimagesize and if it's not an image it will be deleted. Would you say get_headers wouldn't work for this purpose?

Comment: @domino For your usecase, I'd certainly see this as making sense: Look for the `Content-type` header (attention, use case-insensitive matching) and check, if it starts with "image/"

Comment: You can probably use the Content-Type header in this case, as long as you realize it's not foolproof. Btw, I've added code on how to do this to my answer.

Answer (score 4):

Like Eugen Rieck said, you can't be sure whether it's an image without downloading it.
It's always possible for the server to change the Content-Type header to make it seem like an image.

However, after you've downloaded it, you can check it by using this function:

```
if (getimagesize('path/to/image.jpg')) {
    // image
}
else {
    // not an image
}
```

If you want to use the Content-Type anyways, this should work:

```
$headers = array_change_key_case (get_headers ('http://example.com/exampleimage.jpg', 1) );
if (substr ($headers ['content-type'], 0, 5) == 'image') {
    // image
}
else {
    // not an image
}
```

`array_change_key_case()` is used to make all array keys lowercase so the case doesnt make a difference.

Comment: how did I not know array_change_key_case existed? +1

Answer (score 1):

Look for "Content-Type" in the result array and check that it starts with 'image/'

Answer (score 0):

It is pretty simple with this method,

```
$headers = get_headers( 'http://covers.openlibrary.org/b/isbn/9780141323367-S.jpg' );
$image_exist = implode(',',$headers);
if (strpos($image_exist, 'image') !== false) 
{
    echo 'Yups';
}
else 
{
    echo "Nopes";
}
```